# Making sure that S3 data called by Lambda is within AWS cloud [cost reduction]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-billing

Those familiar with Amazon bandwidth costs know that network traffic within Amazon cloud is not billed on condition it's in the same region*.

**: Over-simplification, but that's the general rule of thumb.*

I have a lambda function that calls S3 signed URL's and does some processing on these s3 objects. Those S3 signed url's are passed, along with other parameters, by my application running on EC2.

Those S3 signed URL's look like this: https://bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/object/objectid.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXX%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=XXXXX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=1200&X-Amz-Signature=XXXX

I know that in lambda one should use the AWS functions that can be called by AWS sdk api's. Example documentation for Python3 in my case: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

However, I am quite new to Lambda so I want to avoid rebuilding my code with the risk of vendor-lock in.

So to come back to my question: **is calling signed AWS s3 URL's sufficient to avoid being billed for outside traffic, or should I really use the Amazon SDK's to call s3 objects?**

My Lambda and S3 instances are both in the same region.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that in the case of presigned URL the one who signed the URL is the one who pays. If they are in the same region, nobody pays. At least that is what I could find when googling...

Comment: @luk2302, thanks for your input! Yeah I couldn't find it explicitly.